# Multiple recipients with PHP script?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

So the issue is I want multiple recipients for my PHP form.

What happens is the site user enters there email and then another email for another peroson (for example there doctor).

So what I need is the the doctor to be emailed to.

This is what I am using to know success

```
$mail_to = $field_emaildoc .$field_email;
```

This doesent seem to work?

Any ideas would be great :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option is to add a "Cc" to your header:

```
$sender_email = 'email@domain.com';
$sender_name = 'YOUR NAME';
$send_to = 'email@domain.com';
$send_to_copy = 'anotheremail@domain.com';
$message = 'THIS IS YOUR MESSAGE';
$subject = 'THIS IS YOUR SUBJECT';

$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= "From: $sender_name<" . $sender_email . ">" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Sender: $sender_name<" . $sender_email . ">" . "\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP " . phpversion() . "\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3" . "\n";
$headers .= "X-Sender-IP: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: $sender_name<" . $sender_email . ">" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $sender_name<" . $sender_email . ">" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Cc: $send_to_copy" . "\r\n"; 

mail($send_to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

The problem with this, is that the person receiving the email can see who was copied in. An alternative would be to use: "Bcc" instead of "Cc" or just use the `mail()` function twice and remove the "Cc" or "Bcc":

```
mail($send_to1,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($send_to2,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put *comma* between mail addresses . Look explanation of **to** parameter, here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a comma:

```
$mail_to = $field_emaildoc . ',' . $field_email;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the default [mail](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php) function from PHP.

The recipients are devided by a Comma.

When you want CC and BCC you can set the header. Example from PHP.net:

```
$header .= 'To: Simone <simone@example.com>, Andreas <andreas@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'From: Geburtstags-Erinnerungen <geburtstag@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Cc: geburtstagsarchiv@example.com' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Bcc: geburtstagscheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($empfaenger, $betreff, $nachricht, $header);
```